# C function prototype compile error

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, prototype

I am a novice programmer and I was hoping for some help explaining why the following implementation of a very simple hash function returns a compile error:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define LENGTH 45

int hash(char word[LENGTH+1]);

int main(void)
{
char word[LENGTH+1];
strcpy(word, "HelloWorld");

    //print out hash
    int hash = hash(word);
    // = ( ( (int) word[1] * (int) word[2]) % 1000 ); 

    printf("%i\n", hash);

return 0;
} 

int hash(char word[LENGTH+1])
{
int hash  = ( ( (int) word[1] * (int) word[2]) % 1000 );
return hash;
}
```

The compiler returns the message:

> test3.c:25:24: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer

It is easy enough to simply execute my hash function inside main as a line of code rather than prototyping function, but I would be very grateful if someone could explain why this isn't working.

Comment: Change `int hash = hash(word);` to like `int hash_value = hash(word);`

Comment: as a matter of clarity, assigning the same name to different things ... if you have a function `hash`, it makes sense that you avoid "shadowing" it's name.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, It seems very obvious now that you said it. I can confirm that this works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared a variable with the same name as the function:

```
int hash = hash(word);
```

Variables and functions are in the same namespace in C, so declaring the variable shadows the function. So when the compiler sees `hash(word)`, it complains that you're trying to use an `int` as a function.

Use a different name for one of them.

```
int hashcode = hash(word);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that does it.